# Grafana data source not found

Tags: prometheus, datasource, monitoring, grafana, sre

Everyone. I started using grafana to make it a one stop dashboard for monitoring our infra.  I have multiple prometheus sources and I was able to successfully add them to grafana, however, queries are not able to access the data source through proxy calls. Below is the code that I used for provisioning data sources and the error that it is unable to find the data sources in proxy calls.

**Configuration**

```
    - name: Prometheus-us-south
      type: prometheus
      orgId: 1
      access: proxy
      url: http://trickster.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8480/us-south
      isDefault: false
      version: 1
      editable: true
      jsonData:
        httpHeaderName1: 'Authorization'
      secureJsonData:
        httpHeaderValue1: 'Bearer abcd'
    - name: Prometheus-us-east
      type: prometheus
      orgId: 1
      access: proxy
      url: http://trickster.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8480/us-south-staging
      isDefault: true
      version: 1
      editable: true
      jsonData:
        httpHeaderName1: 'Authorization'
      secureJsonData:
        httpHeaderValue1: 'Bearer abcd'
```

**errors**:

```
t=2021-12-08T19:46:48+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/metadata status=404 remote_addr=10.0.10.5 time_ms=278 size=43 referer="https://dev.monitoring.example.com/monitoring/d/wyTIFC57z/performance-node-health?orgId=1&editPanel=120&inspect=23763571993&inspectTab=query"
t=2021-12-08T19:46:49+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/4/api/v1/metadata status=404 remote_addr=10.0.10.5 time_ms=220 size=43 referer="https://dev.monitoring.example.com/monitoring/d/wyTIFC57z/performance-node-health?orgId=1&editPanel=120&inspect=23763571993&inspectTab=query"
```

**grafana.ini**

```
    grafana.ini:
  paths:
    data: /var/lib/grafana/
    temp_data_lifetime: 24h
    logs: /var/log/grafana
    plugins: /var/lib/grafana/plugins
    provisioning: /etc/grafana/provisioning
  analytics:
    check_for_updates: true
  log:
    mode: console
    level: info
  server:
    protocol: http
    http_port: 3000
    enforce_domain: false
    domain: https://dev.monitoring.example.com/monitoring
    root_url: https://dev.monitoring.example.com/monitoring
    serve_from_sub_path: true
    router_logging: false
    static_root_path: public
    enable_gzip: false
  database:
    type: sqlite3
    host: 127.0.0.1:3306
    name: grafana
    user: root
    max_idle_conn: 2
    conn_max_lifetime: 14400
    ssl_mode: disable
    path: grafana.db
    cache_mode: private
  remote_cache:
    type: database
  dataproxy:
    timeout: 30
    logging: false
    send_user_header: false
  users:
    allow_sign_up: false
    allow_org_create: false
    auto_assign_org: true
    auto_assign_org_id: 1
    auto_assign_org_role: Viewer
    verify_email_enabled: false
    default_theme: dark
    viewers_can_edit: false
    editors_can_admin: true
  auth:
    login_cookie_name: grafana_session
    login_maximum_inactive_lifetime_days: 7
    login_maximum_lifetime_days: 30
    token_rotation_interval_minutes: 10
    disable_login_form: false
    disable_signout_menu: false
```

Appreciate it if someone could help

Comment: It looks your datasource itself is responding with 404 (datasource was found), so make sure your Prometheus is up and running and it is available for the Grafana on configured URLs (e.g. http://trickster.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8480/us-south-staging)